Combine tk GUI and matplotlib with macosx backend without getting SIGSEGV?
I have written a small app which uses a tk GUI to allow the user to enter their parameters, then plots the results of using matplotlib. I would like the user to be able to do this repeatedly without restarting the application.
The issue I have is that if I specify 'macosx' as the backend for matplotlib, the whole application crashes when the user closes the plot window. When we plot window is open they cannot change focus back to the tk window.
I'm on macos Sonoma, Python 3.12 built with pyenv, tk 8.6, latest matplotlib
This crashes if you close the plot window
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tk.Tk()
plt.switch_backend('macosx')
plt.bar(range(10), range(10))
button = ttk.Button(root, text="plot", command=plt.show)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()


Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)

This works, but the plots don't render very well (hence wanting to use macosx)
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tk.Tk()
plt.switch_backend('tkagg')
plt.bar(range(10), range(10))
button = ttk.Button(root, text="plot", command=plt.show)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()


It's best if you don't mix GUI libraries as they handle stuff differently and might interfere with each other. There isn't anything wrong with your code so the only thing you can do is report this as an issue on the matplotlib repo.
